# Trouble calculating percentage

Tags: java

I typed up a election code and I cannot get the percentage of votes for candidates.
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Voting

{
  public static void main (String [] args)
   {
    int candidate1;
    int candidate2;
    int Toronto1;
    int Toronto2;
    int Mississauga1;
    int Mississauga2;
    int Brampton1;
    int Brampton2;
    int total_votes1;
    int total_votes2;
    int totalall;
    double percentage1;
    double percentage2;

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);


    System.out.print("Votes for Candidate 1 from Toronto");
    Toronto1=input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Votes for Candidate 2 from Toronto");
    Toronto2=input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Votes for Candidate 1 from Mississauga");
    Mississauga1=input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Votes for Candidate 2 from Mississauga");
    Mississauga2=input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Votes for Candidate 1 from Brampton");
    Brampton1=input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Votes for Candidate 2 from Brampton");
    Brampton2=input.nextInt();

    total_votes1=Toronto1+Mississauga1+Brampton1;
    total_votes2=Toronto2+Mississauga2+Brampton2;
    totalall=total_votes1+total_votes2;
    percentage1=(Toronto1+Mississauga1+Brampton1)/(total_votes1+total_votes2);
    percentage2=(Toronto2+Mississauga2+Brampton2)/(total_votes1+total_votes2);

    System.out.println("Election Results for Toronto:");
    System.out.println("Candidate 1 = " +Toronto1+ "");
    System.out.println("Candidate 2 = " +Toronto2+ "\n");

    System.out.println("Election Results for Mississauga:");
    System.out.println("Candidate 1 = " +Mississauga1+ "");
    System.out.println("Candidate 2 = " +Mississauga2+ "\n");

    System.out.println("Election Results for Brampton:");
    System.out.println("Candidate 1 = " +Brampton1+ "");
    System.out.println("Candidate 2 = " +Brampton2+ "\n");


    System.out.println("Candidate        Vote             Percentage\n");
    System.out.println("Candidate1         "  +total_votes1+ "                   "+percentage1+"%");
    System.out.println("Candidate2         "  +total_votes2+ "                   "+percentage2+"%");
    System.out.println("Total Votes        "  +totalall+"");

  }
}
```

this is the answer:

```
Votes for Candidate 1 from Toronto [5] 
Votes for Candidate 2 from Toronto [5]
Votes for Candidate 1 from Mississauga [5]
Votes for Candidate 2 from Mississauga [5]
Votes for Candidate 1 from Brampton [5]
Votes for Candidate 2 from Brampton [5]

Election Results for Toronto:
Candidate 1 = 5
Candidate 2 = 5

Election Results for Mississauga:
Candidate 1 = 5
Candidate 2 = 5

Election Results for Brampton:
Candidate 1 = 5
Candidate 2 = 5

Candidate        Vote             Percentage

Candidate1         15                   0.0%
Candidate2         15                   0.0%
Total Votes        30
```

As you can see it says 0.0% instead of 50%.

Comment: *"Can you tell me what is wrong?"* - You're not following [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: I don't see percentage1 or percentage2 in your System.out statements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you're doing int division. An int divided by an int results in an int!

So 20/40 will == 0 since 20 is < 40. If you need a floating point result, use doubles:

```
(double) 20 / 40
```

or for percents, at least multiply by 100 first.

i.e., change

```
percentage1=(Toronto1+Mississauga1+Brampton1)/(total_votes1+total_votes2);
```

to

```
percentage1=(100 * (Toronto1+Mississauga1+Brampton1))/(total_votes1+total_votes2);
```

Comment: @JasonC: no, if it's inside of the parenthesis, it will allow the int division to return a non-zero decimal. I will leave it as it stands.